# How can I implement this feature?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a scriptable object called `Augment Data` that contains a single float. Each instance of `Augment Data` will have a different float. I have a class `Snail` that contains roughly 20 different floats and a list of `Augment Data`. Each `Augment Data` is intended to only be added to 1 specific float in `Snail`.
For example, an instance of `Augment Data` called `HealthMultiplier` with a float value of 0.5f is added to the list in `Snail`. How can `HealthMultiplier` be applied to only the `healthCap` property in `Snail`?

1. I've tried storing a dictionary in AugmentData but Unity doesn't support editing dictionaries in the inspector so that kills the purpose of using scriptable objects.
2. I tried to have Augment Data store another property, a different type of scriptable object called Augment Name that holds a single string. But I still couldn't figure out a clean, expandable way of assigning it to the Snail. (too much to manually change if I want to introduce a new augment data).

Comment: Why do you want to explicitly use SOs as opposed to `float`s?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an abstract method "Apply" to the base class, and implement it in the "HealthMultiplier" class that apply the multiplier value to the corresponding property.

```
public abstract class AugmentData : ScriptableObject
{
    public float value;
    public abstract void Apply(Snail snail);
}

public class HealthMultiplier : AugmentData
{
    public override void Apply(Snail snail)
        => snail.healthCap *= value;
}
```

In the "Snail" class you can loop through the list and call the "Apply" method.

```
public class Snail
{
    public List<AugmentData> list;
    float healthCap;

    public void Start()
    {
        foreach(var a in list)
            a.Apply(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks promising, I'll try it right now and let you know!